# Twitterbot use node and javascript continuously looping

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

It's my first time posting here so apologies in advance if it's not asked correctly.

I'm working on a project where I have a twitter bot that tweets every time a certain account tweets.

I can get it working when I set up a test account but when I do it with the real account (a popular one) my bot will just keep tweeting continuously.

I am basing my code on Daniel Shiffman's twitter bot tutorials on YouTube:

...OK as an edit I have discovered via another forum that the reason is that I am also incoporating any retweets/loves etc of the tweet that I want my bot to react to..as per Twitter API Documentation:

**follow
A comma-separated list of user IDs, indicating the users whose Tweets should be delivered on the stream. Following protected users is not supported. For each user specified, the stream will contain:
Tweets created by the user.
Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
Replies to any Tweet created by the user.
Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
Manual replies, created without pressing a reply button (e.g. “@twitterapi I agree”).**

So what I now need to do is implement some logic so that my bot will only react to the actual tweet of the account I am following and not to any retweets/favourites etc of it..

I have included an if/else statement along with my original code below:

```
    console. log('The streambot is starting');
      var Twit = require('twit'); 
      var config = require('./config'); 
      var T = new Twit(config);


      var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: '(//TWITTERID OF ACCOUNT GOES HERE' });  
      stream.on('tweet',thisTweet); 


/*
if ('statuses/filter' !=  userID){
    console.log("error")
} else {
    thisTweet;
}  */
```

//this IF is to try and limit reaction of my bot only to the tweets of the account I am following

```
function thisTweet(){

            var randomWords= "//a list of random words"

            var splitrandom = randomWords.split(",");

          //picks a random word from list
          var oneWord = splitrandom [Math.floor(Math.random() * splitrandom .length)];

        tweetIt(oneWord);

         }

          function tweetIt(txt){

            var tweet = {
            status : txt 
           }


           T.post('statuses/update',tweet,tweeted);

          }

          function tweeted(err, data, response) {
            if (err){ 
                console.log("something went wrong!");
            }else{
                console.log("It Worked");

            }
          }
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from twitter developers on this one:

This should do the trick:

```
// define the ID of the user we are interested in
var userID = 'some number';

// open a stream following events from that user ID
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: ( userID ) });

    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
        // compare the user ID inside the Tweet object we passed in
        // to check it matches
        if (tweet.user.id == userID) {
            console.log("this was sent by the user we want to track")
            // now do something else
        } else {
            console.log(tweet.user.id + " - " + tweet.user.screen_name)
            // so we can ignore it
        }
    });
```